# Python SimpleGUI Column Loop

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to create a simple GUI (with pysimplegui) with columns based upon folder names and a checkbox underneath that folder name as a heading for each of the files within those folders. I want to be able to have this done in a loop since the number of folders and the contents of them can change. I have a loop working to make a column with the text of the directory name and then checkboxes for each of the items in the folder, but instead of individual columns, I get one long one.

I have tried adding vertical breaks and trying to clear column between calls so that it isn't added to the same one, but it always shows in one really long window instead of columned.

Is there a way to do this, or should I just manually add a column every time I need to add a new category?

```
    col = [[sg.Text(f"{dir}")]]
    for fn in os.listdir(layers + "/" + dir):
        col += [[sg.Checkbox(fn, default=True)]]
    layout += [[sg.Column(col, scrollable=True, size=sz)]]
    col = []

window = sg.Window("Columns GUI", layout)
```

Comment: Still getting the same result using this solution, but your explanation makes sense @JasonYang

Answer (score 0):

```py
layout += [[sg.Column(col, scrollable=True, size=sz)]]
```

It means add a new row in layout, not a new column.

Try

```py
layout = [[]]
...
layout[0] += [sg.Column(col, scrollable=True, size=sz)]
```

Demo code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = [(f'folder {j+1}', [f'File {i+1:0>2d}' for i in range(10)]) for j in range(5)]

layout = [[]]
for dir, files in data:
    column = [[sg.Text(dir)]] + [
        [sg.Checkbox(file, default=True)] for file in files
    ]
    layout[0] += [sg.Column(column, scrollable=True, vertical_scroll_only=True, size=(100, 200))]

sg.Window("test", layout, finalize=True).read(close=True)
```

[image]